# Phrases like «fan-made book», «fan-art» and «fan-fanfiction of this fanfiction»

Tags: перевод

How I should translate phrases like these ones into Russian if I want to avoid simple transliterations from English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pushkin once wrote: "Но панталоны, фрак, жилет - всех этих слов по русски нет".
Fan art as phenomenon widely spread in Russian culture during last 20 years and its form is inspired and influenced by Western culture. So, all these new and borrowed words are intensively used by fans themselves.

Still, if you want to avoid and translate them to Russian then I think this what you'll get:

- Книга, написанная поклонниками xxx
- Творчество поклонников yyy
- Рассказ по мотивам книги, написанной поклонником zzz

All these descriptions are rather long. I think in each particular case we may shorten the name if we look closer on each fan-artifact:

- Пародия на "Звездные войны"
- (Любительская) Постановка по мотивам "Властелина колец"
- Стихи о Бэггинсах*
- Анекдоты о Наташе Ростовой

*персонажи из книги Дж. Р. Р. Толкина "Властелин колец" (If the title is too short, you'll have to put some background information to the footnote).

But all these titles are missing the reference to the fan-art as a phenomenon. You can understand from the context that the book or a story was created by some other author than the original book/movie or that the author is not a professional, but you can hardly see that many people are creating their works based on these books or movies.

So, I don't think this kind of translation will give you any benefits, because fanfics have very [detailed classificaton](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA) (borrowed from English as well), and these фанфик, фан-арт, etc. words are nowadays are used even on news sites like [lenta.ru](http://lenta.ru/news/2013/02/13/bastard/).

Comment: You have done the big work to write this answer, I have to applaud all that cute details placed here.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you probably shouldn't try to avoid it.

«Фан-арт» is used extensively in Russian. Say «фанфик» instead of fan fiction (and it is declined as a normal noun, like «котик»). I don't know how fans call their books… you could use «книга, сделанная фанатами».

If you *really really* want to avoid transliteration, you should probably say «творчество фанатов», «фанатское творчество», «фанатские произведения». But I think you won't be able to translate “fanfiction” without using «фанфик» and without going into long explanations «произведение, созданное фанатами по мотивам…».

Comment: Er...I know that. But what should I do if I hate «фанфик» word. It sounds like «фантик» and contains nothing about fiction that made by fans. I'll keep search to better word.

Comment: @anzo What do you mean, contains nothing? It obviusly has “FAN” and “FICtion” roots. Well, yeah, sounds a bit silly, but… let's be honest, fan fiction is mostly silly.

Comment: @kiralagin When I have said «contains nothing» I meant that «fiction» is all about literature in English and nothing about in Russian. That is why «FIC» means nothing for Russian language user.